# Not able to access Account fields from Opportunity

Tags: apex, soql

I am doing query on Opportunity  from controller to Access account field detail but i am only getting Account Id not any other field.

```
[select  Id, AccountId, Account.name From Opportunity where id in : OppId]
```

I am getting

> USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|saddsa Get Event(Opportunity:{AccountId=001R000000v6FQbIAM, Id=006R0000009aIxEIAU, RecordTypeId=0120000000097UYAAY, CurrencyIsoCode=USD})

Here i am not getting Account Name while i am getting these value in query editor.

Comment: try to debug with relationship name.. in simple debug log it will not display but if you debug the relationship name then it will display. for example `system.debug('----'+objOpportunity.Account.Name);`

Comment: Thanks Ratan i am able to access it by objOpportunity.Account.Name

Answer (score 2):

I believe related fields are not held within the trigger.new context if that is how you are accessing.

You  should try something like this

```
for (Opportunity opp : [select Id, AccountId, Account.name From Opportunity where Id =: Trigger.new]){

 You can then access Account.name in here
}
```